# How do I solve this circuit problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have uploaded an image of the circuit I want to solve. The problem requires solution using Superposition theorem and then verification of the solution using Thevnin's theorem. Using all that I have learnt, I got 16 amps using superposition however I got 4.8 amps using Thevnin's theorem. Please let me know where's the mistake.

[image]

Comment: it seems correct. You can always check your answer by simulation

Answer (score 2):

Thevenin: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLbhKB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

160 volts across 10 ohms is 16 amps

Comment: Please show me the full Thevnin's solution.

Comment: That's all there is - I went straight from looking at your circuit to drawing the picture and in my head calculated the current as 16A. What more is there to do?

Comment: @Pushp: You can get the two Thevenin sources by source transformation (you have two Norton sources; you should know how to transform them into Thevenin sources \$R_{th}\$ = \$R_{N}\$, \$V_{th}\$ = \$I_N R_N\$). Of course the two Thevenin sources can be combined to one: \$V_{th}\$ = 200V - 40V = 160V, \$R_{th}\$ = 5Ohm + 3Ohm + 2Ohm.

Comment: @Curd you forgot the 2 ohm!

Comment: @Andy aka: yes, thanks, added. Actually I meant 2 Ohm (not 3Ohm). Of course all 3 resistors can be added. Then he has to find the short circuit current.

Answer (score 0):

In the thevenin case, part of your calculation of \$V_{ab}\$ includes \$I_{ab}\$. \$I_{ab}\ = I\$ is your answer. There is no need to do \$V_{ab}\$.

But of course given \$V_{ab}\$ (which you have it correctly as 48V), if divided by \$R_{ab}\$, which is 3 (not 10), you get back the same answer of \$I\$.

Comment: But we can't do that. We have to divide the obtained Thevnin's voltage by Thevnin's resistance + the 3 ohm resistance. That's Thevnin's theorem. We can't divide it by 3 simply.

Comment: In this case, the thevenin method implies, convert the left current source and resistor to its thevenin equivalent, and the right current source and resistor to its thevenin equivalent. You have done that. Now use the two thevenin equivalents to get the answer (no more additional thevenin manipulation needed). That is the "thevenin method". After you get a thevenin equivalent, you can use it to help you analyze a circuit as if it is the real thing ("equivalent"). The purpose of thevenin in case is to simplify the analysis.

Comment: I suppose you can find the thevenin equivalent of point a and b without \$R_{ab}\$ then finish the anaylsis that way. Obviously, you will get the same answer. But if you find the thevenin of point a and b with \$R_{ab}\$ included, then it cannot help you in finding the answer because \$R_{ab}\$ is already buried inside this thevenin equivalent.